# circuit to simulate pressing a button twice

Tags: digital-logic

I need a circuit that when reading a push button input will activate a relay for 0.5 seconds ON - 0.5 seconds OFF - 0.5 seconds ON then stay OFF until the push button it's pushed again.

Thank You.

Toma.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not spoon feed you solutions but help you with electronic design problems.

Comment: There are rules and regulations on this site. It isn't a free-for-all forum. The questions you ask have to fit the requirements for the site or the questions will be closed, and deleted. There is a chatroom system in this site where this kind of question is more suited.  I suggest you take your question there. As the question stands at the moment it cannot be answered as it is purely an "I want this circuit, give it to me" question.

Comment: Public service announcement on xkcd: [Free Speech](http://xkcd.com/1357/).

Comment: The sister rule to don't feed the trolls is not to taunt the newbies. Rude and non constructive comments are unwarranted

Comment: This is an interesting question and the solution is more difficult than a casual glance at the question might indicate, so I vote to not close it.

Comment: Actually the *circuit* is incredibly simple: Just a PIC 10F200 and a bypass cap.

Comment: @Passe: Someone that asks a blatant *gimme da codz* question deserves a little poking.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Actually, touting an MCU solution while not providing the wherewithal needed - for one not schooled in the art - to come to the successful end of a quest, smacks of condescension and arrogance.

Comment: @OlinLathrop  You may think that asking for what one needs shouldn't be allowed, but where would you be today if your example was followed by everyone whom you asked for help?

Comment: @EMFi: Give it a rest already.  A microcontroller is the obvious way to do this.  If someone doesn't know them, then this project is a great learning opportunity.  Or they can do it the hard way with 666 timers and the like if they want to.  However, that doesn't make the microcontroller solution wrong.  And no, it's not my obligation to teach microcontrollers just because I mention using them, no more so than we have to teach transistors or resistors in other circuits.  And, asking for help is very different from asking for a solution on silver platter.

Comment: @NickAlexeev just **consider** for a moment to let all the sarcasm go, and actually **help** and **lead by example** as you're supposed to, instead of scaring new users away with demeaning comments.

Comment: @ Majenko, PeterJ, Matt Young, Daniel Grillo, Nick Alexeev: The question is most certainly related to circuit design, and the reason you closed it down is because you didn't like the way the OP asked for help, which is bogus.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: So he asked for a solution; what's wrong with that?  Nothing.  But there **does** seem to be a problem with your [attitude](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHpgFbuo7IY).

Comment: @EMFields It's really annoying that after 10 months and 6000+ rep you STILL don't get how these sites work. The SE model is not designed for _gimme da codz_ questions.

Comment: @MattYoung: Well, Matt, what makes you think I don't know how these sies work? As far as I can tell these are supposed to be  question and answer sites, not  "question and refuse to answer" sites so I'm going to keep on answering whichever questions it pleases me to, not whatever questions _da gangsta boyz_ choose for me to answer.

Comment: @EMFields Ref your comments aimed at The Bearded One, he's past the age where he could learn to improve his attitude. It's a waste of your energy responding to him, or dignifying his posts with acknowledgement - he's never been worth it. You're doing well in trying to help out young'uns, I'm rooting for you. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You asked for a circuit.  Here it is:

[image]

Using a microcontroller is the obvious way to do this.  This is exactly the kind of sequencing and timing a finite state machine is great at, but analog circuitry not so much.  Note how elaborate and relatively complicated the solutions using analog parts like the <s>666</s> 555 timer are.

in this circuit, the pushbutton shorts the micro's GP3 line to ground, which is configured with its internal pullup enabled.  The firmware then does the ON/OFF/ON/OFF sequencing by driving GP2 high for on and low for off.  When high, this applies 5 V to the left end of R1.  The right end will be the B-E drop above ground, so about 700 mV.  That means there will be 4.3 V across R1.  By Ohm's law, that means 4.3 mA of current will flow thru it and into the base of the transistor.  The transistor can be counted on to have a gain of at least 50, so that means it can support relay coil current up to (4.3 mA)(50) = 215 mA.  You didn't specify the relay but there are plenty of relays that can run from 5 V and only take a few 10s of mA.

After the sequence, the firmware makes sure the button is released, then becomes ready again to be triggered by the next button press.  The 10F200 comes with a internal oscillator that is good to a few percent, which will be the accuracy of the on and off timings.  It can also be woken from sleep by transitions on the GP3 pin, so the total circuit current will only be the micro's sleep current when nothing is happening, which is only 2.4 µA in this case.

Comment: +1, it's obviously the right way to go. Especially given that the OP apparently wants to eventually interface the circuit with a GSM receiver.

Comment: Why the Schottky?  Oh, and by the way, I took the liberty of editing your drawing.  Looks much more professional, don't you think?

Comment: @EMFi: The diode is to catch the inductive kickback from the relay coil when switching it off. Without the diode, the transistor would likely get fried. No, the edited drawing does not look more professional. I don't like the sideways pushbutton, the bypass cap that no longer looks like it's tightly coupled to the part, the missing unused PIC pins, and the general aliasing that somehow got in there due to the edit. Please don't edit my schematics.

Comment: I think EM Fields meant why Schottky and not a regular diode, right?

Comment: I'm well aware of what the diode is for, as you must know.  My question, which you seem to be actively dodging, is why you've chosen a Schottky instead of a conventional silicon diode like a 1N4148.  As for the drawing, I realize that it galls you be criticized, but your schematic is just ugly and doesn't even meet the standards that you set up for everyone else to follow.  I mean, do you really think all those messy crossovers and vertical lettering look better than my uncluttered version  of your drawing?

Comment: @Mist: I showed a Schottky because the voltages are low and there is no reason not to.  In general Schottkys are good in low voltage switching applications because they have low voltage drop and are fast, particularly with the reverse recovery being effectively instantaneous for most purposes.  In this case none of these really matter.  The transistor will switch slowly enough with 1 kOhm driving the base anyway.  1N4148 would work for most relays, as long as the coil current isn't too high.  Even a klunky 1N4004 would be good enough due to the slow switching.  I had to put *something* there.

Comment: It just seems strange that someone as knowledgeable as you would show something so obviously out of place when a normal diode would be an instinctive first choice.  And a 4004??? Why on Earth would you need a 400 volt diode when you could use a klunky old 1N4001?  BTW, did you know that if you use a Schottky for a snubber it'll slow down the relay's release? Pretty good reason for not using one, I'd say. Plus, why waste the bucks when you don't have to?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is a homework question or not.  But I'll give you a hint of how I would do this.

You need an astable oscillator with a period equal to your desired ON and OFF time.  A 555 timer works well here.

Then use a packaged counter chip that includes fully-decoded outputs.  A CMOS 4017 comes to mind.  There are other choices as well.

You OR together the desired outputs that correspond to when the relay should be closed.  This can be done with simple passive components - you don't need another chip.

Finally, you need to stop the counter from incrementing when it reaches the count that corresponds to the end of the sequence.

Your trigger / reset input simply resets the counter chip.

Regardless of whether this is homework or not, start putting your design together and post your results by editing your question.  Someone will offer help if needed.

But you have to put the effort in first.

Comment: Thank You for taking the time to respond to my post. I want to install a remote start in my truck and use a gsm relay to start it using my cell phone. I didn't realize that the remote start I got require a button to be pressed twice in order to start the engine. It seems to be a too complicated circuit I will have to build so probably I will just install this remote start on my wife car and  look for a remote start that require to press a button for a few seconds for starting the engine.

Comment: Dwayne, if the time of the first and third pulses needs to be the same, a 555 astable isn't a good choice for the clock generator because the first output pulse is some 40 to 50% longer than the rest of the pulses.

Comment: I normally do the cheap and nasty 555 timer setup using a CMOS device (TLC555): a single RC with the resistor coming from the output (pin 3).  I had assumed that the 555 is running all the time but even if it's not, just take the first pulse from the 2nd output on the counter (leave the 1st output alone).

Comment: @EMFields: There's a trick to deal with the odd first pulse--check my schematic.

Comment: @supercat: Nice; It works! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the circuit shown below will do what you asked for, and here's how it works:

A 555 needs to be triggered by a low-going pulse (Vcc to GND) which lasts for less time  than the output pulse does.

When triggering it with a manual switch, such as S1, below, the 555's TRIGGER input needs to be pulled up to Vcc with a resistor, R2, and the low generated by grounding the switch needs to be differentiated so that the TRIGGER input will only see a short spike when the switch is made, and R1 and C1 do that.

Then, when S1 is released, R1C1 will become a charge pump and will generate a single high-voltage pulse which might damage the 555 if D1 wasn't there to clamp it to Vcc plus a diode drop.

The output pulse time, in seconds, is \$ \ \ t = 1.1 RC \$, where R is the resistance of R3, in ohms, and C is the capacitance of C2, in farads.

[image]

U2 and U3 are functionally identical to U1, but instead of being operated with manual switches, when U1 times out, the low-going edge of U1-3 is used to trigger U2, then when U2 times out its low going output is used to trigger U3. The result is that three pulses will be generated, shifted in time, with U1-3 and U3-3 ORed with D4 and D5 and used to drive Q1, which in turn drives K1 whenever U1-3 or U3-3 is high, like this:

[image]

Then I found [this](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NE558_3.pdf), available [here](http://www.futurlec.com/Linear/NE558Npr.shtml) for USD 0.65.

Sigh...

Comment: @David: You're right. It's done!

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier and have a lower part count and cost with a microcontroller and a transistor or optó coupler. A standard push button code example would be all that you really need.

Comment: A 558 goes for about 65 cents and, including the passives should let the oscillator and the decoder come in for under a dollar, US. Plus, no learning curve.

Comment: A 10F200 goes for 50 cents, and that's in single quantity.  The oscillator is built in, and there is no need for a decoder.  The learning curve is free is you A) already know PIC programming, or B) feel its a useful thing to know anyway.  If neither of those apply, then go ahead and practise the ancient rituals.

Comment: Same for attiny and msp430 value line chips, and both have extensive online code examples. Typical tutorials already have a push button and led blink examples require absolutely zero learning curve.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Y'know, Olin, I used to think that you had some control over being a dick, but the more I read your stuff the more I'm convinced the gratuitous flames are pathological in nature.  For example, your latest cutesy reference to 555s as 666s and your: "go ahead and practice the ancient rituals" are designed to be derisive and really - as I understand it - have no place here.  You've been here for a long time and you must surely have read the accepted codes of conduct and yet you persist in your narcissistic fol-de-rol. Do you have any idea why you can't be nice?

Comment: @Passerby: "Zero learning curve" implies _a priori_ knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the schematic for the circuit that I suggested.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnviod.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You trigger the circuit by applying a 12V signal to the Start line.  The output line is normally open (high) but is pulled LOW twice.  The time period is set by R1 & C1.

Note that you can easily alter the timing of this circuit by simply choosing different output pins on the 4017.

We ignore the 1st output because the oscillator is free-running and we don't know how long the 1st output will be active.  So we ignore it and use the subsequent outputs - these all have the same timing.

Comment: Why post another answer when you could just have updated your previous one?

Comment: I don't think that'll work well because START isn't synchronous with the 555's output. Consequently, the width of the first pulse will be random.  Why don't you run a simulation and check it out?

Comment: Plus, if START goes low before the sequence is over, it'll abort.

Comment: @EM Fields: I think that I address your 1st concern: re-read the 3rd paragraph.  We ignore the 1st output for that very reason.  Regarding your 2nd point: the circuit doesn't actually begin the sequence until the reset line is released.  I considered adding a RC differentiator to the reset input but figured that if this was coming from a vehicle remote control, the delay until the button was released wouldn't matter.

Comment: It goes through a two-pulse sequence with a long first pulse on power-up, but if that's not a problem it works perfectly after that. Here's a link to the [files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6gta07khu8fs3rz/AABE4wd1wYKPc0ugO_vi7L73a?dl=0) needed for an LTspice simulation.  If you're interested, download them all into the same folder and left-click on the .asc file to get things started

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to achieve the desired effect using two 555 timers; the one on the right will generate pulses roughly 0.5 second on 0.5 second off while it's enabled; the one on the left will enable it for about 1.8 seconds.  Capacitor C4 will cause U2 to start in the middle of an "off" cycle; this will slightly delay the first turn-on event, but will ensure that all turn-on events are the same length.  R6 exists primary to limit a massive current spike on the output of the first 555; it should be small enough not to adversely affect things otherwise.  C3 could probably be implemented easily as a 10uF and 4.7uF in parallel.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flXWO1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Very nice, and a 556 would make it a single chip solution. I've added an LTspice schematic and a plot, and fiddled with the first stage timing to get the gate to be the right width.

Comment: @EMFields: When I used the Falstad simulator, the reset wire caused the discharge wire to 'track' whether the cap was above or below VDD/3 while the output stayed low, but the schematics I've seen for the 555 don't justify that behavior, so for simulation I wired the output through and inverter and MOSFET and used that in place of DIS.  Do real parts behave as shown in the Falstad simulator or the schematics?

Answer (score -1):

Toma, use two 555 timer circuits.  Search the web for "555 timer circuits" and find one that does what you need.

Comment: Since there are three timing intervals it cant be done with two 555s.

Comment: @EMFields: A 555-based oscillator has two configurable intervals--the "on" time and the "off" time.  If one enables a 555-based oscillator for about two cycles' worth of time, one can get two pulses out of it.  It may be helpful to have a cap whose value is about half that of the second timing cap, wired, with a small series resistor, between the output of the first 555 and the timing cap of the second to help equalize the length of the first pulse with that of the second.

Comment: @supercat: Sorry,  I can't quite visualize what you're proposing. Could you post a schematic as an answer, please?

Comment: @EMFields: I started to post one, but the editor here has a horrible schematic symbol for the 555 and it doesn't simulate it, so I don't know how to draw it and confirm it works.

Comment: @supercat: Linear has a nice simulator [here](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) with a decent schematic editor and a 555 model in its library. Plus, it's free :)

Comment: @EMFields: I like the Falstad simulator, even though its 555 symbol isn't perfect and I don't think its reset pin is simulated quite right; would you like a design with that?

Comment: Sure. Just post the schematic, though, and I'll redraw it and run it in LTspice.

Comment: @EMFields: Posted.  I used a custom-box part rather than the built-in 555 but the layout is still rather crummy.  Perhaps you can do better?